# Member function used as lvalue

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, lvalue, member-functions

I'm implementing a Complex class as exercise, and I'm looking at this [file](http://espec.ppgia.pucpr.br/doc/gnu/libstdc++/complex-source.html) as guideline.
At some point in this file I found a strange overloaded operator:

```
template<typename _Tp>
    inline complex<_Tp>
    operator+(const complex<_Tp>& __x, const _Tp& __y)
    {
        complex<_Tp> __r = __x;
        __r.real() += __y;
        return __r;
    }
```

How It's possible to use `__r.real()` as `lvalue`? I tried to implement it in my class, along with the two overloaded definitions of `real()`, but of course it gives me back a number of errors.
Could someone tell me what I'm missing?

Those are the definitions of the functions `real()` and `imag()`:

```
template<typename _Tp>
    inline _Tp&
    complex<_Tp>::real() { return _M_real; }

template<typename _Tp>
    inline const _Tp&
    complex<_Tp>::real() const { return _M_real; }

template<typename _Tp>
    inline _Tp&
    complex<_Tp>::imag() { return _M_imag; }

template<typename _Tp>
    inline const _Tp&
    complex<_Tp>::imag() const { return _M_imag; }
```

Comment: The definition you show for `real` return a reference which is an lvalue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition you show for non-const `real` return an a reference `_Tp&` which can be used as an `l-value` just fine. I am guessing your version does not return a reference and therefore will not work.

This article [Understanding lvalues and rvalues in C and C++](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c/) is a great reference on this topic.

Comment: I decided to choose your answer because of the article you linked which could be very useful to deepen the topic of this question.

Answer (score 3):

Its `real()` is returning a reference to the `_M_real;` member. The reference can be used as an lvalue.

To make yours able to do the same, you'll need to return a reference as well.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the implementations return a `_Tp&`; that is, a **reference** to `_Tp`. This makes the return value an l-value.